# $f(x,y)=(x+y)^3\sqrt{x^2+y^2} +\cos(x+y)-1 $ has a max/min at (0,0)? (1,-1)?

Tags: calculus

> Does the function
>
> $$f(x,y)=(x+y)^3\sqrt{x^2+y^2} + \cos(x+y)-1 $$
>
> have an extremum in $(0,0)$ ? $(1,-1)$?

The function isn't differentiable at $(0,0) $ (because of the $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $  , and I can't find any suitable neighborhood of this point that will give me positive values (because $\cos(x+y)-1<0$ always)

Will you please help me ?

Thanks

As for $(0,0)$ - we can take $(x,0) $ with $x\uparrow 0 $ (i.e. $x<0$ ) and get $f(x,0)<0$ . I can't find any such neighborhood with $f>0$ so I don't know how to determine if it is a saddle point or not...

Comment: For a local minimum, no. Of course, there is no global min or max. Perhaps you can show your approach and we can review.

Comment: What gives you the impression that the function is not differentiable at the origin? The factor with the third power makes it so flat that the point of the square norm is hidden. It would be different for higher derivatives. You can also use $1-\cos(2A)=2\sin^2(A)$.

Comment: OK. for example for $(0,0)$ , if I take $y=x$ , and tend to zero, then I get $f(x,x)=8\sqrt{2}x^3 \sqrt{x^2} -sin^2 (2x)$ .
The second term is always positive, and the first one is negative for negative $x$ . For positive $x$ , we can't decide whether $f(x,x)$ will be positive or negative. 
So, we again get negative values ... How can I deduce something? Thanks

Comment: In addition, for the derivative of $f(x,x)$ we get that :
$f(x,x)= 8\sqrt{2}\cdot 3 x^2 \cdot \sqrt{x^2} +8\sqrt{2}x^3 x/\sqrt{x^2} -2sin(2x)cos(2x) $ and I have no idea if this is positive or negative around zero.

Comment: $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and $df(0,0)=0$. .

Comment: OK... So how can I determine if (0,0) is min or max ? The fact that the differential is zero makes it critical...